# Why TIMESTAMP instead of DATETIME in this instance?

Tags: t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2014

In many examples I've read of SQL timestamp useage, a typical case would be that a timestamp column is added to prevent a kind of race condition whereby a user is changing data that has lost it's integrity since another user 'got in there first'.

More specifically, prior to issuing an update on a row, business logic would cross check the timestamp they believe to be changing so that there isn't a mix up with row versioning.

### Question

Why wouldn't DATETIME suffice for this task? In fact, by that logic - why wouldn't any unique data type be appropriate instead? NEWID() every time an update is issued, for example?

Comment: In my experience, a short integer suffices.

Comment: @Pointy - I don't see any reason it wouldn't, which is where my confusion lies. This is such a widely-provided example that I'm unsure on what I'm missing.

Comment: Which DBMS are you talking about?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - SQL Server 2014.

Comment: A `timestamp` in SQL Server does **not** store "date and time".

Comment: [timestamp (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776(v=SQL.90).aspx): *The timestamp data type is just an incrementing number and does not preserve a date or a time*

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I know. My question is why couldn't you use any data type that could present an order or uniqueness.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález - yep, I know, see comment above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mySQL, timestamp is a physically smaller datatype to store than datetime. In addition, timestamp is universal, ignoring all timezones. For international products, this is important.

ID's are not recommended as they often generate at the point of insert/update.

Answer (score 2):

It appears I missed the fundamental feature of timestamp, it auto updates.

So calling `UPDATE` on a row will automatically increment it's `TIMESTAMP` column without me manually setting it.

I'll leave this answer here just in case anybody has comments about what else I may have missed.